# show / hide an only one of a multiple of elements on the same page w/ jquery

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I've got a page where I'm having several different sub-nav elements on it on various

My mark-up is (basically)

```
<div class="sub-nav">
 <div class="sub-nav-btn"></div>
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="sub-nav">
 <div class="sub-nav-btn"></div>
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="sub-nav">
 <div class="sub-nav-btn"></div>
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

my current jquery is

```
$('.sub-nav ul').css("display","none");
$('.sub-nav-btn').click(function(){
$('.sub-nav ul').toggle();
return false;
});
```

currently this works but opens all of the relevant elements called. How do I get the jquery working so it only calls the relevant element and not all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HIya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/4aMwA/ **or** more organized fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/s2CtY/

`slideToggle` http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

So the way this work is I have put some sample text for demo ** click on `foo` and you will see its  `ul` and if you click on `fp` you will see its `ul` sliding down so on and so forth.

**jquery code**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

 $('.sub-nav ul').css("display","none");
    // Watch for clicks on the "slide" link.
    $('.sub-nav-btn').click(function () {
        $(this).next(".sub-nav ul").slideToggle(400);
        return false;
    });


});​
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sub-nav ul').hide();
$('.sub-nav-btn').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('ul').toggle('slow');
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/B9dSA/)